# Integer value of gives unexpected result

Tags: java

While working on a project of mine, I came across a problem.

When I run the following program:

```
public class test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String x = "1234";
        System.out.println("Int value: " + Integer.valueOf(x.charAt(0)));
        System.out.println("String value: " + x.charAt(0));
    }
}
```

it gives me the result:

```
Int value: 49
String value: 1
```

which left me confused because `x = "1234"`, so when it runs the forth line the result should be the same as:

```
System.out.println("Int value: " + Integer.valueOf(1));
```

which should in theory should give me: `Int value: 1`

So what caused the result to be `49` instead?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There's a difference between

```
System.out.println("Int value: " + Integer.valueOf(1));
```

and

```
System.out.println("Int value: " + Integer.valueOf(x.charAt(0)));
```

In the second line what's really happening is this -

```
System.out.println("Int value: " + Integer.valueOf('1'));
```

Notice that '1' is being passed as a Character not as an Integer. As a result the Integer.valueOf return the ASCII value of character '1', which is 49.

Refer to the [ASCII table](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/1/1b/ASCII-Table-wide.svg/2000px-ASCII-Table-wide.svg.png) to see for yourself.

Answer (score 3):

this is because following return UTF-16 value, rather than value itself

```
        System.out.println("Int value: " + Integer.valueOf(x.charAt(0)));
```

try using `int x = Integer.parseInt("1234");` instead

Comment: To be more precise, it's UTF-16 code unit value, not ASCII. It's the same for “1”, though, but it's still a very important difference.

Comment: Now that this answer is the most correct, it can be rounded out with the ubiquitous link to character tables: [Unicode](http://unicode.org/charts/nameslist/), [UTF-16 code unit for '1'](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/0031/index.htm).

Answer (score 1):

49 is the decimal value that corresponds to the ASCII character '1'. Take a look at this chart, and look at the "Dec" (decimal value) column that corresponds to Chr (character value) '1'.

[A link to an ASCII table that shows you how a given character maps to a given decimal](http://www.asciitable.com/)

Answer (score 1):

You used the function `valueOf(String s)`, not `valueOf(int i)`. [Documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html) says, that it "returns an Integer object holding the value of the specified String.". It's mean, that function returns ASCII code of sign "1", which is 49.

Comment: Actually it is exactly the opposite, it took a character '1' and interpreted it as integer thus returning integer ascii code of '1' which is 49. So in the original problematic code the method that was used was `valueOf(int i)`

Answer (score 1):

This is because you were printing the ASCII value of 1.

Try [Character.getNumericValue(char)](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html#getNumericValue(char))

Try this (with minimal change from your implementation):

```
package general;

class CharToInt
{
public static void main(String[] args) {
      String x = "1234";

      System.out.println("Int value: " + Character.getNumericValue(x.charAt(0)));
      System.out.println("String value: " + x.charAt(0));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

What you needed to do is pass a String "1" into method "Integer.valueOf()" then it would parse it to integer 1. To do so you could do this

`String x = "1234";
System.out.println("Int value: " + Integer.valueOf(s.substring(0,1));`

Answer (score 1):

one thing is how you see the argument passing to the function, but the second thing is what is the type of this argument.

```
x.charAt(0) returns '1'
```

but must remember that the type is *character*.

So, in fact it returns the binary data like: `00110001` which one can read like `0x31(hex)` what is `49(dec)` what is the UTF-16 representation of character `'1'`.

Now... the function:

```
Integer.valueOf( )
```

It expectes the number as argument, so it takes those binary data  `00110001` and reads it like a normal number... to it is value of 49